# enable Open edX custom theme bitnami

Tags: bitnami, openedx, custom-theme

I am trying to customize the default UI of open edX. But I am not getting far enough. I am new to this. I am getting confused reading the docs. In the documentation it is telling me to place my theme in the '/opt/bitnami/edx/var/themes/edx-platform' directory. But there is not any such directory. So should I make my own directory in the default location of my remote server? Again I found a directory that has path like this '/opt/bitnami/edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/themes'. So do I put my custom theme here or create my own directory? Also can anyone provide me clear steps which I can follow. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think Open edX documentation is very clear, relevant, and concise. Of course, we can argue but that's how I feel.

Its not a good idea to make changes in  '/opt/bitnami/edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/themes'.

Use the comprehensive theming method for custom themeing, you can find more [here](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/apps/edx/configuration/install-default-theme/).
First, you need to develop your own theme, theme development guide [here](https://edx.readthedocs.io/projects/edx-installing-configuring-and-running/en/latest/configuration/changing_appearance/theming/create_theme.html).

Thene make these changes to your 'lms.yml' and 'studio.yml' in '/opt/bitnami/edx/etc/'.

```
 COMPREHENSIVE_THEME_DIRS:
 - /path/to/edx-platform/themes

 ENABLE_COMPREHENSIVE_THEMING: true,
 DEFAULT_SITE_THEME: 'your theme name'
```

And restart the LMS, CMS service, and compile assets.

You can use open edX native installations also. More info [here](https://edx.readthedocs.io/projects/edx-installing-configuring-and-running/en/latest/installation/native_installation.html).